# jasmine not logging on the console the tests

Tags: node.js, express, jasmine, supertest, jasmine-spec-reporter

I am using Jasmine Framework to test my RESTful API. When I run the tests, it works fine. **However, jasmine is not logging the usual spec tests...** I only get a log if there is an error and the final result result, as shown below:

```
1 spec, 0 failures Finished in 0.044 seconds Randomized with seed 19717 (jasmine --random=true --seed=19717)
```

**This is an example of test file**

```
import { OrderStore } from '../../models/order';
import { logger } from '../../logger';

describe('OrderStore', () => {

  let orderStore = new OrderStore();

  describe('index method', () => {
    const test = 'should fetch orders and have the expected properties';
    it(test, async () => {
      try {
        // logger.warn(`Test: index method: ${test}`);
        const orders = await orderStore.index();
        expect(Array.isArray(orders)).toBe(true);
        expect(orders.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
        orders.forEach((order) => {
          expect(order.id).toBeDefined();
          expect(order.quantity).toBeDefined();
          expect(order.order_status).toBeDefined();
          expect(order.created_at).toBeDefined();
          expect(order.product_id).toBeDefined();
          expect(order.user_id).toBeDefined();
        });
        // logger.warn(`Index method test passed successfully`);
      } catch (err) {
        // logger.error(`Index method test failed: ${err}`);
        throw err;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

So, as you see, Jasmine is not logging each test and description. Do someone knows what can be?

I am adding here the jasmine config file (jasmine.json)

```
{
  "spec_dir": "dist/tests",
  "spec_files": ["**/*[sS]pec.?(m)js"],
  "helpers": ["helpers/**/*.?(m)js"],
  "junit": {
    "suppressSpecReporter": false
  },
  "env": {
    "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
    "random": true,
    "reporters": [
      {
        "name": "jasmine-spec-reporter",
        "options": {
          "displayPending": true,
          "displayStacktrace": "all",
          "displaySuccessfulSpec": true,
          "displayFailedSpec": true,
          "displaySpecDuration": true,
          "displaySuiteNumber": true,
          "colors": {
            "success": "green",
            "failure": "red",
            "pending": "yellow"
          },
          "displaySpecErrorsSummary": true,
          "displaySummary": true,
          "displayFailuresSummary": true,
          "displayPendingSpec": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

More Infos:
Node Version: v18.1.0
Npm version: 8.8.0
Jasmine version: 5.1.0
Jasmine-spec-reporter: 7.0.0
Supertest: 6.3.3

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide me with any advice!

Thanks!
Turtles

Comment: I don't know the answer specifically but you most likely need to play around with Custom Output here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spec-reporter. Click on the see how link. Or maybe you can clone the Github and see if the Node project has the report as to how you would like it and see if you can mimic it: https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter/blob/673e22cd3b13732b421a25e862dbe887692ed345/examples/node/spec/node-spec.js.

Comment: I do not know either. I will check these links... Thanks!